# Loop to add one row at a time to list

Tags: python, list, csv

I have the code below to create a list of ItemID's and other fucntions that create other Lists from csv. I have tried writing a function to loop though and add one line at a time to the other lists(for every ItemID add a new price row), instead of every loop creating the full list.

```
def Main(filename1, filename2):
    with open(filename1, "r") as csv1, open(filename2, "r") as csv2:  
        csvReader1 = csv.DictReader(csv1)
        csvReader2 = csv.DictReader(csv2)

        ItemIDList = []
        for row1, row2 in zip(csvReader1, csvReader2):  
          ItemIDList.append((row2["ItemId"]))
    return ItemIDList

def buildObject(ItemIDList):

    for row in ItemIDList: getPrice(filename1, filename2)
    for row in ItemIDList: NameList = getName(filename1, filename2)

def getPrice(filename1, filename2):
    with open(filename1, "r") as csv1, open(filename2, "r") as csv2:  
        csvReader1 = csv.DictReader(csv1)
        csvReader2 = csv.DictReader(csv2)

        priceList = []
        for row1, row2 in zip(csvReader1, csvReader2):  
          csvPVList.append((row2["Price"]))
        return priceList
```

Main builds the ID list, getPrice is the function im trying to re-write to only add one row at a time from the csv every loop in buildObject.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Which part is not working as expected?

Comment: In `def Main...`, the row `TradeList.append((row2["ItemId"]))` will throw errors because `TradeList` is not defined.

Comment: @Ralf getPrice is creating the entire list at once at the minute, not adding one row at a time in the loop. I only want to add a new row in the priceList list for every row in the itemIDList

Comment: @Ralf corrected

Comment: Try sending the `row` to `getPrice` instead of the filenames

Comment: @doctorlove It wont run without the filenames/filelocation

Comment: It's helpful to add a couple lines of sample data.

Comment: @caot for this example the itemID row would contain data such as 14359D and the price would be 1234.2 . Although the data contained isn't super important as im not sure what base logic to apply to the function to start with to get were I want to end up

Answer (score 0):

This is a design problem. Reading files from disk is an expensive operation and should be done only once. And loading both csv files in memory to zip them is not memory efficient. So you should:

- have a single extractor method/function that reads both files one line at a time and feeds  lists (or lists of tuples/namedtuples/objects) with all the data that will be next used
- have this extractor to return those lists

Code could be (highly simplified, no error processing), if using individual lists:

```
def extract_data(filename1, filename2):
    with open(filename1, "r") as csv1, open(filename2, "r") as csv2:  
        csvReader1 = csv.DictReader(csv1)
        csvReader2 = csv.DictReader(csv2)

        ItemIDList = []
        priceList = []
        for row1 in csvReader1:
            row2 = next(csvReader2)
            ItemIDList.append(row2["ItemId"])
            priceList.append(row2["Price"])
            ...                                    # eventually extract other fields
    return ItemIDList, priceList
```

Or if using namedtuples:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Record = namedtuple("ItemId", "Price")
...
            recordList = []
            for row1 in csvReader1:
                row2 = next(csvReader2)
                recordList.append(Record(row2["ItemId"],row2["Price"]))
        return recordList
```

Comment: There's two reasons why originally I have them as individual functions for each column as above. The first being I am taking the ItemID from two csvs, so I have another function that reduces that down to only unique values. The second being I'm using the lists to create a Item object in my __init_ function, which is easier to do if each individual function is a individual column

Comment: @Heredity: Whatever the processing, you should try to process the files only once and keep in memory what you have to extract. Then do your stuff from the values you have in memory.

Comment: What would you recommend as the best way to read once into memory but keep individual functions

Comment: @Heredity: a first function should extract the relevant informations from the csv files, then the unique function should use the list(s) returned from that first function. But this is no more than my own advice, and may not be adapted to your specific use case.